# In SQL Server, how to have select return empty string and not null when null

Tags: sql-server

I have a nullable varchar and even when it is null, I want my select to return an empty string and not null.  That is

```
SELECT FIRST, LAST 
FROM CUSTOMER
```

What I want is if `FIRST` is null, I want the return to be `""`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use

```
SELECT COALESCE(FIRST, ''), LAST FROM CUSTOMER
```

This has the advantage of being more portable (COALESCE is part of the SQL Standard, ISNULL isn't)

You can also use an arbitrary number of arguments, like

```
SELECT COALESCE(FIRST, SECOND, THIRD, '')...
```

And COALESCE will use the first non-null value encountered

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT isnull(FIRST,'') AS FIRST, LAST FROM CUSTOMER
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select isNull(First,'') from customer
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COALESCE(FIRST, ''), LAST FROM CUSTOMER
```

would work also

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ParamParserFn]
    (
      @delimString VARCHAR(255) ,
      @delim CHAR(1)
    )
RETURNS @paramtable TABLE
    (
      [Index] INT ,
      [Token] INT
    )
AS 
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @len INT ,
            @index INT ,
            @nextindex INT ,
            @counter INT ,
            @data VARCHAR(50)

        SET @len = DATALENGTH(@delimString)
        SET @index = 0
        SET @nextindex = 0
        SET @counter = 0


        WHILE ( @len + 1 > @index ) 
            BEGIN

                SET @nextindex = CHARINDEX(@delim, @delimString, @index)

                IF ( @nextindex = 0 ) 
                    SET @nextindex = @len + 1



                INSERT  @paramtable
                        SELECT  @counter ,
                                SUBSTRING(@delimString, @index,
                                          @nextindex - @index)


                SELECT  @index = @nextindex + 1 ,
                        @counter = @counter + 1
            END


        RETURN
    END
```